# DetailsView Update ItemTemplate on Select

Tags: c#

I have a GridView that has records in it. When you select one of the records it updates the detailsview so you can makes changes. I have them set as templates. One of the fields that I am pulling from SQL is a number 1-4 (A priority level). I want it so that when you select the record in the gridview, it shows the data in the Detailsview. Now, as of right now, it showing the number. But I wrote another method to convert the number into text (switch statement) to show what the number mean. This page is written as a ASCX files, just fyi. I need to know what code that I need to on the back end to make it so that my method can switch the number for Label6 it the text.

I omitted some code to save time.

```
    <asp:DetailsView ID="dvRequestDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4"
                            DataKeyNames="casenumber" DataSourceID="RequestDetails" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Small"
                            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="300px" 
                            EnableModelValidation="True" 
                            onpageindexchanging="dvRequestDetails_PageIndexChanging">
                            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" />
                            <EditRowStyle BackColor="WhiteSmoke" />
                            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                            <Fields>    
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="other">
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetailsOther" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                            SelectedValue='<%# Bind("other") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="4" Selected="True">General</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">Low Priority</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">High Priority</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">Critical</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("other") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                    </InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("other") %>' OnDataBound="dvRequestDetails_DataBound"></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
</Fields>
                        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#E9ECF1" Font-Bold="True" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                    </asp:DetailsView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call methods in your code behind from the aspx page easy enough.

Code Behind with method to convert priority to a string (I have assumed it is an int)

```
public partial class DemoPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected string GetPriorityName(object priority)
    {
        switch ((int)priority)
        {
            case 1:
                return "Critical";
            case 2:
                return "High Priority";
            case 3:
                return "Low Priority";
            case 4:
                return "General";
            default:
                return "Unknown";
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the aspx just call this method passing in your value

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="dvRequestDetails" runat="server">
    <Fields>    
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Priority" SortExpression="other">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetailsOther" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                    SelectedValue='<%# Bind("other") %>' OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Value="4" Selected="True">General</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Low Priority</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="2">High Priority</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="1">Critical</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox6" runat="server" Text='<%# GetPriorityName(Bind("other")) %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text='<%# GetPriorityName(Bind("other")) %>' OnDataBound="dvRequestDetails_DataBound"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Fields>
</asp:DetailsView>
```

Seeing as you now have the list of priorities twice (once in the aspx and once in the code behind) you would probably be better off making it a list and binding the drop down list to that as well as reading the name from it in-case you decide to change a name / add another priority it only needs to be done in one spot.